# How Windows looks for shared files, printers, etc

Tags: windows, algorithm, diagram, shared, printers

I have a big problem finding information on how Windows search for resources (shared files, printers, etc) in more detail. I am looking for information that I could present in the form of an algorithm for a presentation to school. If anyone has such a source of information I would be grateful. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I am interested in the mechanism of how Windows finds hosts in LAN and questions them about their shared folders.

Comment: Do you want to find all shared files or something else?

Comment: I want to find all shared files. Yes.

Comment: Maybe start here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc181373.aspx